# Replace the placeholder - the tilde ~ with the actual content using regular expression and sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
<d:entry id="_2udw" d:title="roughshod"><d:index d:value="roughshod" d:title="roughshod"/><span class="hw">roughshod</span><br/><span class="tag3">a.</span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span><span class="tag4"></span><span class="tag1">(马匹)</span>钉有防滑蹄铁的</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span>残暴的;残忍的;无情的:</span><span class="ex">a tyrant's ～ rule </span><span class="ex_c">暴君的残暴统治</span><hr class="hr_1"/>ride ～ over / 残暴地<span class="tag1">(或盛气凌人地)</span>对待;对…横行霸道;对…不予同情:<br/><span class="ex">ride ～ over the people </span><span class="ex_c">骑在人民头上作威作福</span><span class="ex">ride ～ over the rights of the children </span><span class="ex_c">践踏儿童的权利</span><span class="ex">ride ～ over sb.'s feelings </span><span class="ex_c">伤害某人的感情</span><span class="ex">The boss rode ～ over the men when they asked for higher wages. </span><span class="ex_c">工人们要求加薪,老板不予理睬。</span></d:entry>
<d:entry id="_2u05" d:title="rookie"><d:index d:value="rookie" d:title="rookie"/><span class="hw">rookie</span><br/><span class="tag3">n.</span><br/><span class="tag4"></span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span>新兵;生手,新手:</span><span class="ex">a police ～ </span><span class="ex_c">警察新手</span><span class="ex">a ～ star </span><span class="ex_c">新星</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span><span class="tag1">(第一年参加联赛的职业球队的)</span>新队员，新秀</span><span class="tag2"><br/>[词典校勘] <br/></span> <span>rookie现在通用翻译为“新秀”。 另外，括号中说法有歧义。</span></d:entry></d:dictionary>
```

Now I'd like to replace all ～ in the code snippet with the title of the corresponding entry.

The expected results are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
<d:entry id="_2udw" d:title="roughshod"><d:index d:value="roughshod" d:title="roughshod"/><span class="hw">roughshod</span><br/><span class="tag3">a.</span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span><span class="tag4"></span><span class="tag1">(马匹)</span>钉有防滑蹄铁的</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span>残暴的;残忍的;无情的:</span><span class="ex">a tyrant's roughshod rule </span><span class="ex_c">暴君的残暴统治</span><hr class="hr_1"/>ride roughshod over / 残暴地<span class="tag1">(或盛气凌人地)</span>对待;对…横行霸道;对…不予同情:<br/><span class="ex">ride roughshod over the people </span><span class="ex_c">骑在人民头上作威作福</span><span class="ex">ride roughshod over the rights of the children </span><span class="ex_c">践踏儿童的权利</span><span class="ex">ride roughshod over sb.'s feelings </span><span class="ex_c">伤害某人的感情</span><span class="ex">The boss rode roughshod over the men when they asked for higher wages. </span><span class="ex_c">工人们要求加薪,老板不予理睬。</span></d:entry>
<d:entry id="_2u05" d:title="rookie"><d:index d:value="rookie" d:title="rookie"/><span class="hw">rookie</span><br/><span class="tag3">n.</span><br/><span class="tag4"></span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span>新兵;生手,新手:</span><span class="ex">a police rookie </span><span class="ex_c">警察新手</span><span class="ex">a rookie star </span><span class="ex_c">新星</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span><span class="tag1">(第一年参加联赛的职业球队的)</span>新队员，新秀</span><span class="tag2"><br/>[词典校勘] <br/></span> <span>rookie现在通用翻译为“新秀”。 另外，括号中说法有歧义。</span></d:entry></d:dictionary>
```

In Sublime editor, with a small portion of the xml file, I could replace (.*d:value=")([^\n]*?)("[^\n]*?)([~～]) with \1\2\3\2 to achieve that purpose(Although I need to do it multiple times to replace all the ～). But the whole xml file is too large for the editor to actually replace it, the editor just hangs dead. So I'm considering using sed command. I have tried the following:

```
sed -i "" -E 's|(.*d:value=\")([^\n]*?)(\"[^\n]*?)([~～])|\1\2\3\2|g' test.xml
```

But it gives me the errors like "RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid". This is the first time I try the sed command.

I don't know if the regex is different in sed command or something else.
I have tried for a few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Oh, and I'm on the Mac OS platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to post also required output.
Anyway I think you are looking for recursive replace something like this:

```
sed ':r;s/\(^.*d:value="\)\([^"]*\)\(".*\)\([~～]\)/\1\2\3\2/g;tr'
```

Test:

```
$ sed ':r;s/\(^.*d:value="\)\([^"]*\)\(".*\)\([~～]\)/\1\2\3\2/g;tr' test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
<d:entry id="_2udw" d:title="roughshod"><d:index d:value="roughshod" d:title="roughshod"/><span class="hw">roughshod</span><br/><span class="tag3">a.</span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span><span class="tag4"></span><span class="tag1">(马匹)</span>钉有防滑蹄铁的</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span>残暴的;残忍的;无情的:</span><span class="ex">a tyrant's roughshod rule </span><span class="ex_c">暴君的残暴统治</span><hr class="hr_1"/>ride roughshod over / 残暴地<span class="tag1">(或盛气凌人地)</span>对待;对…横行霸道;对…不予同情:<br/><span class="ex">ride roughshod over the people </span><span class="ex_c">骑在人民头上作威作福</span><span class="ex">ride roughshod over the rights of the children </span><span class="ex_c">践踏儿童的权利</span><span class="ex">ride roughshod over sb.'s feelings </span><span class="ex_c">伤害某人的感情</span><span class="ex">The boss rode roughshod over the men when they asked for higher wages. </span><span class="ex_c">工人们要求加薪,老板不予理睬。</span></d:entry>
<d:entry id="_2u05" d:title="rookie"><d:index d:value="rookie" d:title="rookie"/><span class="hw">rookie</span><br/><span class="tag3">n.</span><br/><span class="tag4"></span><br/><span class="table"><span class="num">1.</span>新兵;生手,新手:</span><span class="ex">a police rookie </span><span class="ex_c">警察新手</span><span class="ex">a rookie star </span><span class="ex_c">新星</span><span class="table"><span class="num">2.</span><span class="tag1">(第一年参加联赛的职业球队的)</span>新队员，新秀</span><span class="tag2"><br/>[词典校勘] <br/></span> <span>rookie现在通用翻译为“新秀”。 另外，括号中说法有歧义。</span></d:entry></d:dictionary>
```

Comment: I have tried this command on my machine. With sed, it doesn't work;It just outputs the same content as that of the xml file. But when I use it with gnu-sed, wow, it suddenly works, don't know why. Many thanks, Kubator.

Comment: By the way, what are the :r; and tr at the end for?

Comment: Glad if helped. That's the recursive part, it means if substition successful repeat command on address :r

Comment: I see. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: I tried this on the 89MB xml file, after a few hours, the command is still running and the file has not changed. For some reason this will not work on big files.